How does an AC signal in a Transistor Amplifier Circuit swing output voltage if it is going below 0.7V?
I'm new to electronics and trying to understand something:

Looking at a basic NPN Transistor Amplifier circuit, I'm trying to understand how the output voltage amplifies and inversely follows the input voltage given that the input voltage goes below the "turn-on" voltage of the transistor into the cut-off region.
If we say the "turn-on" voltage for the transistor is 0.7 V, and a DC voltage is held at the base at 0.7 V to keep the transistor on, by feeding a 2 V peak-to-peak (1 V amplitude on either side) input signal which rides this DC voltage, the voltage at the base will peak on either end at +1.7 V and -0.3 V.
My question is, once it swings below 0.7 V (the entire "negative swing" of the AC voltage), shouldn't the transistor be "off" that entire time and the output signal would just be held at the supply voltage of 10 V until the voltage at the base rises past 0.7 V again?
Thanks for your help

You're right: 2V pk-pk is too much input signal for this amplifier. Try decreasing input 10mv ballpark if you're wanting a linear amplifier.

Simulators are free so, instead of guessing what the voltages will be why don't you simulate your circuit and make an improved and reliable question based on facts.

Yes, your analysis is correct. That particular amplifier can't handle a 2 Vpp input signal without "clipping". That's the name of the effect that occurs when the transistor is driven into cutoff or saturation.
The problem is that without some resistance in the emitter lead to provide negative feedback, the amplifier has a very high gain. Any input signal that would have an output amplitude that exceeds the supply voltage of the amplifier will end up getting clipped.

Thanks for your input Dave.
So is my analysis correct and the issue here is that the Vpp is too much (as someone else suggested as well)?
Is the way around it making sure the input signal is small enough peak-to-peak to ensure it remains within the range of voltage at the base that keeps the transistor on?

@user1390491 Just to add another note, because the gain of your amplifier depends strongly on the input signal value at any given moment, this amplifier stage also is highly distorting of larger signal inputs. $r_e^{:'}$ varies with the signal. So this kind of stage almost always finds itself in larger circuits with the use of global NFB to correct the distortion. By itself the high distortion is either ignorantly ignored or isn't important due to a very small input signal, if not ignored. Rb is also usually a poor way to bias -- depends too much on the BJT.
